# Pushpin for Windows Phone App 8.1 similar to Windows Map App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a requirement where i need to show a pushpin for a particular location.
I have able to add a custom pushpin as the PushPin class is now deprecated.
The code for which is as follows:

```
var location= new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 19.4034, Longitude = 73.8312 });
        var pin= CreatePin();
        mapper.Children.Add(pin);
        MapControl.SetLocation(pin, location);
        MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(pin, new Point(0.0, 1.0));
        mapper.TrySetViewAsync(location, 16, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Bow);
```

Code for the Custom CreatePin is:

```
 private DependencyObject CreatePin()
    {
        //Creating a Grid element.
        var myGrid = new Grid();
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        myGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        //Creating a Rectangle
        var myRectangle = new Rectangle {Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), Height = 20, Width = 20};
        myRectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        myRectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        //Adding the Rectangle to the Grid
        myGrid.Children.Add(myRectangle);

        //Creating a Polygon
        var myPolygon = new Polygon()
        {
            Points = new PointCollection() {new Point(2, 0), new Point(22, 0), new Point(2, 40)},
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
        };
        myPolygon.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
        myPolygon.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        //Adding the Polygon to the Grid
        myGrid.Children.Add(myPolygon);
        return myGrid;
    }
```

I am able to show the custom pin now however can not show the title.Is there a way i can achieve a pin like used in windows map app

What i get Now:

[image]

What i want:

[image]

Something like this.Or if this is not possible a way to add title to pin.
Please do not suggest MapIcon as i have tried it and it doesnt show up the mapicon unless zoomed in, also i found its not quite reliable

> The MapIcon is not guaranteed to be shown. It may be hidden when it obscures other elements or labels on the map.
>
> The optional Title of the MapIcon is not guaranteed to be shown. If you don't see the text, zoom out by decreasing the value of the ZoomLevel property of the MapControl.
>
> When you display a MapIcon image that points to a specific location on the map - for example, a pushpin or an arrow - consider setting the value of the NormalizedAnchorPoint property to the approximate location of the pointer on the image. If you leave the value of NormalizedAnchorPoint at its default value of (0, 0), which represents the upper left corner of the image, changes in the ZoomLevel of the map may leave the image pointing to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to show the text along in a row along with the polygon and rectangle .This is as close i could get.

```
private DependencyObject CreatePin()
    {
        //Creating a Grid element.
        var myGrid = new Grid();
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        myGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        //Creating a Rectangle
        var myRectangle = new Rectangle {Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), Height = 20, Width = 20};
        myRectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        myRectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        //Adding the Rectangle to the Grid
        myGrid.Children.Add(myRectangle);

        //Creating a Polygon
        var myPolygon = new Polygon()
        {
            Points = new PointCollection() {new Point(2, 0), new Point(22, 0), new Point(2, 40)},
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
        };
        myPolygon.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
        myPolygon.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        TextBlock newtextblock = new TextBlock();
        newtextblock.Text = "hello";
        newtextblock.FontSize = 15;
        newtextblock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        newtextblock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        newtextblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        myGrid.Children.Add(newtextblock);
        //Adding the Polygon to the Grid
        myGrid.Children.Add(myPolygon);
        return myGrid;
    }
```

[image]

This does look very ugly. But this is all i could think of. If there is a better way for achieving this, please post the answer. Still waiting for more answers.

Comment: This is fine if you're trying to emulate the old form of push-pins, but the new API with [MapIcons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx) seems to be a better option

Comment: I have tried MapIcons using this code  MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
            MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(startLocation);
            MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            MapIcon1.Title = "Space Needle";
            mapper.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);    However the icon doesnt shop up until zoomed in a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can create style and you can give it as a style like this:

```
 <Style x:Key="PushPinFirmaStyle" TargetType="bm:Pushpin">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="51"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="54"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="DataContext"  Value="{Binding }"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-26,-54,26,54"/>

        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="grdItem"   DataContext="{Binding}" >
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/icon/tesis.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NAME}"  Margin="20,12,22,20 " Foreground="#003260"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>


                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and you can set it like this:

```
Bing.Maps.Pushpin p=new Bing.Maps.Pushpin();
p.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["PushPinFirmaStyle"];
```

Answer (score 0):

look friend there's already a ready made PushPin class in a namespace called "Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit" , if you can't import this namespace into your project then you need to add it , you can done this by going to the TOOLS>Library Package Manager>Package Manager Console , then write this command "Install-Package WPtoolkit"

[image]

after you done this you need to reference it inside the xaml code :

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

then you can easily add the pushpin in C# :

> ```
> using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
> using System.Device.Location;
> using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
> using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
> using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;
> ```

```
Pushpin pin = new Pushpin()
        {
            Content = "MyPushpin",
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
            BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
        };
MapOverlay relay = new MapOverlay()
        {
            Content = pin,
            PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoordinates // myGeoCoordinates is an object of the class GeoCoordinate
        };
MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
layer.Add(relay);
myMap.Layers.Add(layer); // myMap is the name of your map control
```

this should be the result :

[image]
.

hope this helps :)

PeaceBeUponYou (Y)

> > References :
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/806054/Windows-Phone-Location-Map-Pushpin
>   http://phone.codeplex.com/